# setup.py install develop with virtualenv - Bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, virtualenv, setup.py, virtualenvwrapper

I've got a folder called `Packages` in my home folder. In this folder I want to develop some packages. To test them I tried to install the package with

```
python setup.py install develop
```

while inside the environment, of course. This gives me the following output

```
develop
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing BACnetScapy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to BACnetScapy.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to BACnetScapy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'BACnetScapy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'BACnetScapy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/BACnetScapy/BACnetLayers.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/BACnetScapy/BACnetTags.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/BACnetScapy/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/BACnetScapy/BACnetFunctions.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/BACnetScapy/BACnetConstants.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy/BACnetLayers.py to BACnetLayers.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy/BACnetTags.py to BACnetTags.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy/BACnetFunctions.py to BACnetFunctions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BACnetScapy/BACnetConstants.py to BACnetConstants.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying BACnetScapy.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying BACnetScapy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying BACnetScapy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying BACnetScapy.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/BACnetScapy-1.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing BACnetScapy-1.0-py2.7.egg
Copying BACnetScapy-1.0-py2.7.egg to /home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding BACnetScapy 1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BACnetScapy-1.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for BACnetScapy==1.0
Finished processing dependencies for BACnetScapy==1.0
running develop
Checking .pth file support in build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

So the problem seems to be that the `build` folder which is automatically created in the package folder is not on the `PYTHONPATH` - but why should it be? And how should I add it to the `PYTHONPATH`? I tried to add this folder with

```
add2virtualenv /home/lk/Packages/BACnetScapy/build
```

but that did not work, either. 
What am I doing wrong?

This is my `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="BACnetScapy",
    author="lk",
    version="1.0",
    packages=["BACnetScapy"],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

The folder looks like that

```
/BACnetScapy
    |
    |-/BACnetScapy
    |       |- some.py
    |       |- modules.py
    |       |- __init__.py
    |       |-/data # a folder containing some data the package needs
    |
    |-setup.py
```

Answer (score 3):

The command should be `python setup.py develop`, not `python setup.py install develop`